# Is there a way to extract/replace just the last folder in the windows batch file path variable %1? trying to use it as part of the file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd, contextmenu

Seems a good place as any to ask

So I want to assign a file name being processed by a batch file to:
`LASTFOLDERIN%1PATHNAME-FOLDERNAME.rar` using the `%1` Windows sends me from the context menu.

So far I'm able to ALMOST make it, I get so far as:

```
WinRAR.exe a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\Sorting\ %~p1-%~n1.rar" "%~1\*.*"
```

Which returns:

```
\FULL(DIR1\DIR2\DIR3)PATH\-FOLDERNAME.RAR
```

But the problem is I get the FULL path (multiple directories), not just the very last one, also, I get the `\` that breaks the whole thing.

Question is, is there a way to extract just the last folder in the path variable %~1 that I get from the windows context menu argument?

Or if not, can I somehow replace the `\` with `-` so I can rename the files manually later? to get something like this: `-DIR1-DIR2-DIR3-FOLDERNAME.RAR`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm stuck here.

PS I'm sending `%V` to the batch file, since `%1` did all kinds of weird things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you asked: "Now if anyone knows how to get the last 2 directory variables instead of just the last one... it would be awesome haha."

My answer was: "Simple: after `set "PATHNAME=%1"` use `set "last1=%PATHNAME:\=" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=%" & set "lastTwo=!last2!\!last1!"` The result is in `%lastTwo%`"

I think this is fairly simple code (just two lines). Anyway, here it is such a code, with the mod required to also get the third-to-last directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "PATHNAME=%1"

set "last1=%PATHNAME:\=" & set "last3=!last2!" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=%"

echo Full path name:   %PATHNAME%
echo Last dir only:    %last1%
echo From 2nd to last: %last2%\%last1%
echo From 3rd to last: %last3%\%last2%\%last1%
```

Output example:

```
Full path name:   DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\DIR4\DIR5
Last dir only:    DIR5
From 2nd to last: DIR4\DIR5
From 3rd to last: DIR3\DIR4\DIR5
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I've found something that is definitely not elegant but does the job, if anyone can improve by all means, this is the best I could do and it gets the job done, here's the code for the batch files:
(Thanks to Squashman for the working code for spaces and recursive dirs)

For last dir only

```
for %%G in ("%~dp1\.") do set "PATHNAME=%%~nxG"
"WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\%PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar" "%~1\*.*"
```

Returns: LASTPATHDIR-SELECTEDDIR.RAR file in a specific folder, id wish I could add this to the drag and drop handlers but alas I cant only DLLS can be there, so this is the next best thing, I just change the batch file whenever I need it stored somewhere else, you can call a path variable instead on the batch file and just update it whenever you need it changed if you like, so you dont have to change all the batch files every time.

For 2nd to last + last dir:

```
for %%G in ("%~dp1\.") do set "PATHLAST=%%~nxG"
for %%G in ("%~dp1\..") do set "PATH2NDLAST=%%~nxG"
set PATHNAME=%PATH2NDLAST%-%PATHLAST%
ECHO Processing %PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar"
"WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\%PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar" "%~1\*.*"
```

for third to last + second to last + last:

```
for %%G in ("%~dp1\.") do set "PATHLAST=%%~nxG"
for %%G in ("%~dp1\..") do set "PATH2NDLAST=%%~nxG"
for %%G in ("%~dp1\..\..") do set "PATH3RDLAST=%%~nxG"
set PATHNAME=%PATH3RDLAST%-%PATH2NDLAST%-%PATHLAST%
ECHO Processing %PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar"
"WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\%PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar" "%~1\*.*"
```

make sure to make 3 different batch files and call them accordingly.

If anyone cares here's the accompanying code for the right click context menu.

(just make sure the archiver batch file and the winrar path is added to the path environment variable)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;--============== CR =============--

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CRARFILE1]
@="Add to SORTING (Last)"
"Icon"="WinRAR.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CRARFILE1\command]
@="\"(ArchiverLast).bat\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CRARFOLDER1]
@="Add to SORTING (Last)"
"Icon"="WinRAR.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CRARFOLDER1\command]
@="\"(ArchiverLast).bat\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CRARFILE2]
@="Add to SORTING (2ndLast)"
"Icon"="WinRAR.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CRARFILE2\command]
@="\"(Archiver2ndLast).bat\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CRARFOLDER2]
@="Add to SORTING (2ndLast)"
"Icon"="WinRAR.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CRARFOLDER2\command]
@="\"(Archiver2ndLast).bat\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CRARFILE3]
@="Add to SORTING (3rdLast)"
"Icon"="WinRAR.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CRARFILE3\command]
@="\"(Archiver3rdLast).bat\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CRARFOLDER3]
@="Add to SORTING (3rdLast)"
"Icon"="WinRAR.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CRARFOLDER3\command]
@="\"(Archiver3rdLast).bat\" \"%V\""
```

Delete any entries you don't need (like if you only need the last one)

If you want to do that quickly here's a batch file to do it, it will append this path to your path variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
setx Path "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\WinRAR\" /m
```

Hope this helps others, its saved me so much work so far

Comment: well that was short lived, it works but breaks with directories with a space... I cant find out why any help would be appreciated

Comment: `for %%G in ("%~dp1\.") do set "lastFolder=%%~nxG"`

Comment: EDIT: found a fix, updating code now

for %%I in (.) do set PATHNAME=%%~nxI

Comment: Your solution worked great squashman, updating the answer with your solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Now if anyone knows how to get the last 2 directory variables instead of just the last one... it would be awesome haha.

Comment: Simple: after `set "PATHNAME=%1"` use `set "last1=%PATHNAME:\=" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=%" & set "lastTwo=!last2!\!last1!"` The result is in `%lastTwo%`. BTW to get the last one, just use: `set "last=%PATHNAME:\=" & set "last=%"`

Comment: @Squashman: In the `%%~nxG` part the modifiers just get the (last) Name without extension (because the provided folders have no extension), so the `"%~dp1\."` part don't require the Drive nor the Path. I think that `for %%G in (%1) do set "lastFolder=%%~nG"` get the same result...

Comment: @XionicFire add a period to the code I gave you and see what happens.

Comment: @Squashman what do you mean add a period? where do i add it? to the path var (dp1?)

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have assumed you would see the existing period in my code.  Two periods: `"%~dp1\.."`

Comment: @Aacini i think you give me too much credit on my knowledge of this, i do not quite understand what you meant with your code, the best i understood how to modify my code was:

`for %%G in ("%~dp1\.") do set "PATHNAME=%1"
set "last1=%PATHNAME:\=" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=%" & set "lastTwo=!last2!-!last1!" 
ECHO Processing %lastTwo%-%~n1.rar"
"C:\System\Installed\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\%PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar" "%~1\*.*"`

Comment: But this returns:
`C:\Test\a\b>for %G in ("C:\Test\a\b\\.") do set "PATHNAME="C:\Test\a\b\28""

C:\Test\a\b>set "PATHNAME="C:\Test\a\b\28""

C:\Test\a\b>set "last1="C:" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=Test" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=a" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=b" & set "last2=!last1!" & set "last1=28""   & set "lastTwo=!last2!-!last1!"

C:\Test\a\b>ECHO Processing !last2!-!last1!-28.rar"
Processing !last2!-!last1!-28.rar"

C:\Test\a\b>REM "C:\System\Installed\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\"C:\Test\a\b\28"-28.rar" "C:\Test\a\b\28\*.*"`

Comment: I had to change one of your slashes to a - since windows doesn't allow files with \ in the filename, but even with or without slash the command does not work, it returns the full path, I'm super sure its something i screwed up and your code seems to extract all the paths separately I just don't know how to get it to work because I'm not as well versed in the whole what does %. ! or ' means to the command interpreter.

If you can modify the whole code and paste it as it should be i can probably figure out what i did wrong, thanks for the help

Comment: @Squashman so close! adding a second dot ALMOST did the trick, it gave me the second and last path but not the second to last path, maybe add a third dot?

This is what came up
`"C:\System\Installed\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\a-28.rar" "C:\Test\a\b\28\*.*"`

Comment: @Squashman my current code is: `for %%G in ("%~dp1\..") do set "PATHNAME=%%~nxG"
ECHO Processing %PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar"
"C:\System\Installed\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\%PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar" "%~1\*.*"`

Comment: @Squashman oh wait i get your point, use the same code twice, one for the second to last and one for the last  and add them up in the filename, that might work let me try it out

Comment: So you know that one DOT gives you the last directory and two DOTS gives you the second to last directory.  How could you use that to create a variable with both of them.

Comment: @Squashman well effin ell that did it... it returns the last and second last paths, it only works for 2 paths tho, (I tried a third dot but no dice haha), I feel Aacini's solution can probably do that if I can figure out how to get it to work, but for now this works great! heres the code: `for %%G in ("%~dp1\.") do set "PATHLAST=%%~nxG"
for %%G in ("%~dp1\..") do set "PATH2NDLAST=%%~nxG"
set PATHNAME=%PATH2NDLAST%-%PATHLAST%
ECHO Processing %PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar"
REM "C:\System\Installed\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -u -m0 -y "C:\[Sorting]\%PATHNAME%-%~n1.rar" "%~1\*.*"`

Comment: @Squashman Thnx so much for the assist Squashman you are a total lifesaver, this is saving me so much time.

Comment: This is a basic concept that most programmers learn about in their first semester of programming.  The single dot and double dots are consistent across many operating systems. Third to last `%~dp1\..\..`  You ever run the `DIR` command from the command prompt and wonder why it shows an entry for `.` and `..`?

Comment: ahh I've done this for decades, I'm just not a formal programmer perse, more of a jack-of-all-trades IT guy, and I figured as much that that's what they did I just didn't know I could call on those from batch files, ill experiment with that \..\.. code and make several versions! thanks again!